# Using Facelets with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, facelets, jakarta-mvc

The new Java EE 8 MVC ([JSR 371](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mvc-2280472.html)) is planning to use facelets as the view technology for MVC.

Is it a bad idea to use facelets with Spring MVC?
e.g. https://github.com/acichon89/springmvcfacelets

There seems to be almost no support for this online yet there is a huge community of JSF Facelets users and it will be supported in JSR 371 so not sure why Facelets gets no love from the Spring community.

Personally I find the thymeleaf syntax more difficult to read and I have zero interest in natural templating and much prefer the facelets decorator approach.

Comment: As the linked JSR itself points out, JSF+Facelets and Spring MVC represent two different styles of MVC - JSF follows a view-oriented style and Spring MVC an action (or request) oriented style. I am voting to close this question as being opinion-based because different people will tend to favour one approach over the other so it is unlikely to be an objective answer to it.

Comment: I'm not asking about JSF with facelets...I'm asking if facelets is safe to use with Spring MVC. This question has absolutely nothing to do with JSF.